# Our team wanted to use ansible UI, so I deployed ansible Semaphore, Now I have issue Migrating playbooks to semaphore

Tags: ansible

Can someone let me know how I can migrate ansible playbooks that are nested in azure repos, so we basically have a project in azure repos, Under azure repos we have multiple sub-repos contains ansible playbooks. Is there a way to migrate all the playbooks to semaphore into single project or I need to create individual project for each playbook we have.?

Comment: What does "nested in azure repos" mean? Could you provide approximate structure?

Comment: I mean we have a project and inside that project we have subfolders that contains ansible playbooks for each task we created folder and places some shell scripts and playbooks.

Comment: Structure is like Azure Repos > project > subfolders > playbooks

Comment: Hm, I think it should be Pull Request to Semaphore project.

Comment: Yeah, pull request is working but semaphore couldn't find playbook inside sub-folders.

Comment: Did you try to specify path to playbook in field `Playbook filename`? Something like `project/subfolders/playbooks/site.yml`

Comment: Yes, I even tried the ssh and http url , I mean both ways.

Comment: I mean this: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/914224/174242406-b000e026-3217-4559-b2bb-7ed0a9130890.png

Comment: No, I didn't tried this, Thanks for this update, I will try this and post you message.

Comment: Thanks for the snap you posted with that i was able to configure playbooks, cheers.